# implementing datastructures in java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

During my college days I used to do programming about datastructures like trees, linked  list, bst, b tree in C/C++. But now I have been working on Java for last 2 years.

How can I implement such datastructures in Java?

Comment: This question could also be: "How to implement anything in Java?".

Comment: its specific to datastructures, as i thik pointers are very imoprtqant in implemting those, and java doesnnot have pointers

Answer (score 1):

> its specific to data structures, as i think pointers are very important in implementing those, and java does not have pointers.

Java does have the equivalent of pointers.  They are called "object references" or just plain "references".

Granted there are differences between C/C++ style pointers and Java references.  (For instance you cannot do arithmetic on Java references or cast Java integers to references.)  But none of these "limitations" prevent you from implementing general purpose data structures.  Indeed, if anything it is easier because you don't need to worry about memory management ... in most cases.

Other answers provide references for text books on data structures using Java as the primary exposition language.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the same as C++.

The syntax is almost the same, just you don't have pointers - you have reference.

Everything is by reference, so if you claim that you know C++, just think about it as all the functions get their parameters with a **&** for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My instructor used this book to teach java data structures:

[Data Structures and Abstractions with Java, 2/e](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,3110,013237045X,00.html).

You can look through the [source code](http://media.pearsoncmg.com/ph/esm/esm_carrano_DSAJava2e/Carrano2e_StudCode.zip) used in the book.

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/carrano/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointers you can use Objects they work almost he same as pointers if you want I can upload you an example when I get home of Sparse Matrix in Java. Its a lot easier implementing Data Structures in java because you dont have the problems of memomry allocation Java does it for you... and about implementing lets say you had structs like node that contained Item right and left same thing in java objects heres an example

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> left;
    Node<T> right;


    public Node<T>(T data, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and getters and setters